# SAML 2.0 LOG OUT issue

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I use saml 2.0 with  ADFS 2 for single sign on in 
windows server

I am able to login.But logout becomes impossible.The error thrown is :

Exception details:

2)Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7054: The SAML logout did not complete properly...............

Comment: Please edit your question. It is too messy to be read and understood.

Comment: Please check the event log or debug trace for more details. This is typically due to the target RP/IDP to whom ADFS issued a SAML logout message is erroring out or does not get back a response.